# Water level sensor for a coffee machine boiler

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, water

I made a simple water level sensor with an Arduino. A digital pin  supplies 5V to a probe in a coffee machine boiler. Boiler chassis is connected to AC ground (earth) and the ground to an analog IO pin on Arduino. A pull down resistor is between the analog pin and GND pin on Arduino. If there's water in the boiler, the analog pin detects the voltage, if there's not, it reads zero.

The digital pin is turned on every 1s to slow down corrosion of the probe.

Now, a lot of things are connected to the AC ground - the pump, boiler heater, power supply etc. Should I do anything to protect the Arduino in case anything goes wrong? Is there a better design for this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZHfG5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdFhbx.png)</sup>

Comment: To be perfectly clear, by AC ground do you mean earth ground or neutral?

Comment: And there's a "Custom component" you can use to represent the microcontroller board.

Comment: We need to see how the Arduino power supply is connected. Is the power supply ground also earth ground or ac neutral? You are expecting to pull the earth ground line high with respect to the Arduino ground, and that sounds a little sketchy to me.

Comment: I think you've identified the critical idea to worry about: corrosion. (Though I might broaden it into a wider scope of migration of charged particles.) Potential differences (volts) regardless of cause (galvanically connected dissimilar metals or ground loop caused, etc.) can be a problem over time.

Comment: You can dramatically reduce corrosion by using AC. Use a capacitor to couple to your probe, in series with R1, replace R2 with a capacitor. Drive D1 up, measure, drive it down, measure.

Comment: The Arduino's GND is galvanically isolated from the device's earth?!

Comment: Hmm, I think I don't have enough EE knowledge to post here yet.   

@Neil_UK I can oscillate D1 between 0V and 5V. But the water level sensor is mechanically connected to earth, don't I need to oscillate between -5V and 5V to prevent corrosion?

Also, why is corrosion a major problem? I'm running about 2V through the probe for less than ~10ms daily. Is this going to destroy my probe in the next 2 years? I tested 2 models of espresso machines and neither of them used AC for water level probes.

Comment: @JimmyB In my circuit there's a wire directly going from the Arduino's GND to the device's earth (power plug earth), but I'm not sure what is the question.

Comment: Just to clarify, the circuit above works, I'm using it now. The original post was asking whether I should  isolate Arduino's GND from earth (power plug ground) in case something goes wrong other devices connected to the same earth.

Comment: Then the circuit in your diagram is not what you have built. If the Arduino's GND is also connected to earth so is A1 (IN), so you will never read anything but 0 from that analog input.

Comment: Your title says _"Water level sensor for a coffee machine boiler"_ but your question is about something completely different.